# What does "by some margin" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I found [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190230/meaning-of-by-some-margin).

> China is North Korea’s biggest trading partner **by some margin**.

That means the trading amount is nearly 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the list of [trading partners](http://www.worldstopexports.com/north-koreas-top-import-partners/), China is by far the largest compared to the rest. By [some](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/some) [margin](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/margin) here means by a considerable  margin:

North Korea's Top Trading Partners:

> China: US$1.7 billion (90.8% of total North Korean exports)
>
> Pakistan: $29.2 million (1.6%)
>
> India: $26.1 million (1.4%)
>
> France: $12.4 million (0.7%)

***[Some:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/some)***

> *large amount or number of something:*
>
> - It'll be some time before we meet again.
> - We discussed the problem at some length.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Oh~~~~, Finally I got it. It looks like 2 pieces of paper, one on the other. One almost covers another by there is a margin.